# What are the alternatives to the magic punctuation "$|" to turn off the print buffer in Perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

I was refactoring some old code (by other people) and I came across the following at the top of some CGI scripts:

```
#Turn on output buffering
local $| = 1;
```

perlcritic as usual unhelpfully points out the obvious : "Magic punctuation used". Are there any alternatives to this or perlcritic is just grumpy?

Furthermore, on closer inspection. I think the code is wrong.

If I'm not mistaken, it means exactly the opposite from what the comment says. It turns **off** the output buffering. My memory is a little bit rusty and I can't seem to find the Perl documentation that describes this magic punctuation. The scripts run in mod_perl.

Does messing around with Perl's buffering behavior desirable and results in any performance gain? Most of the stuff written about this comes from the early part of the first decade of the 21st century. Is this still even a valid good practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems a bit scattered, but I'll try my best to answer thoroughly.

You want to read [`perldoc pervar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). The [relevant section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) says:

```
   $|      If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.  Default is 0
           (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or not; $| tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to
           flush after each write).  STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal and block buffered otherwise.  Setting this
           variable is useful primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket, such as when you are running a Perl program under rsh and want
           to see the output as it's happening.  This has no effect on input buffering.  See "getc" in perlfunc for that.  See "select" in perldoc
           on how to select the output channel.  See also IO::Handle. (Mnemonic: when you want your pipes to be piping hot.)
```

So yes, the comment is incorrect.  Setting `$| = 1` does indeed *disable* buffering, not turn it on.

As for performance, the reason output buffering is enabled by default is because this improves performance--even in 2011--and probably until the end of time, unless quantum I/O somehow changes the way we understand I/O entirely.

The reasons to disable output buffering are not to improve performance, but to change some other behavior *at the expense of performance*.

Since I have no idea what your code does, I cannot speculate as to its reason for wanting to disable output buffering.

Some (but by no means all) possible reasons to disable output buffering:

- You're writing to a socket or pipe, and the other end expects an immediate response.
- You're writing status updates to the console, and want the user to see them immediately, not at the end of a line.  This is especially common when you output a period after each of many operations, etc.
- For a CGI script, you may want the browser to display some of the HTML output before processing has finished.

Comment: It generates a gigantic report in the form of large table. Typical stuff.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you'd want to disable buffering for the output of the report, then. If running the report takes a while, and you display some sort of status during the reporting, then you may disable buffering for the filehandle where status updates are sent, as mentioned in my newly-edited answer.

Answer (score 9):

`$|` is one of a number of punctuation variables that are really per-filehandle.  The variable gets or sets the value for the currently selected output filehandle (by default, STDOUT).  (`$.` is slightly different; it is bound to the last filehandle read from.)

The "modern" way to access these is via a method on the filehandle:

```
use IO::Handle;
$fh->autoflush(1);  # instead of $|=1
```

The method corresponding to each variable is documented in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7C).

Comment: `STDOUT` there is a filehandle

Answer (score 4):

The comment, as others have stated, is incorrect. In contrast, `local $| = 1` disables output buffering.

To comply with [`Perl::Critic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic)'s policies, you could make use of the [`English`](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html) module:

```
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

local $OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH = 1;  # equivalent to: local $| = 1
```

Comment: Perl is always full of surprises (some good, some bad). I've used Perl for a long time and I've never come across the English module. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check in manuals, $|=1 turn off buffering saying that it is true that the buffers must be flushed, so the comment is wrong.

About it being good or not, I don't know, but me too have seen that always done in CGI scripts, so I suspect it is a good thing in this particular case, maybe it is since normally CGI scripts want to make the data available as soon as they are written.